# Computing the standard part of $(3-\sqrt{c+2})/(c-7)$ where the standard part of $c$ is $7$

Tags: calculus, limits, nonstandard-analysis

I'm working through Keisler's calculus book based on infinitesimals. The following problem has me a little bit stumped.

Compute the standard part of:
$$\frac{3-\sqrt{c+2}}{c-7}$$
Given that $c\ne7$ and $st(c) = 7$ where $st(x)$ is the standard part function. I know that $$\lim_{c\to7}{\frac{3-\sqrt{c+2}}{c-7}}=-\frac{1}{6}$$ I can't for the life of me though figure out how to work this out using standard parts. I'm probably being dumb. Help?

Comment: Have you tried rationalizing the numerator?

Comment: It is the same proof as the usual calculation of the limit, with no gain (or loss).

Comment: Yep. I'm a moron. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Try multiplying by $\frac{3+\sqrt{c+2}}{3+\sqrt{c+2}}$